# Add name of file in column within csv being exported

Tags: powershell, csv

I am getting the info I need from the files, but I need to have a column that shows the actual log that it is pulling it from.

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse -filter *.log | 
    get-content | select-string -pattern "dummy" | 
    group path | select name | export-csv "c:\temp\kent.csv"
```

I am looking for something like this per line: 
Two columns:

> **Name of log location :** c:\temp\logs\1.log
>
> **Reference of the DUMMY remark in log :** http://dummy.CORPORATE.LOCAL/SMS_DP_SMSPKG$/bf91665c-4e7b-441a-8bda-87d60a5b8bbe]LOG]!>

Comment: Can we see some desired output in an [edit]. Not sure what you are going for here. Do you want a list of all directories with targeted files? I want to know why you are grouping them. `Get-Content` is part of the issue here

Answer (score 1):

One crux of your code is that you are breaking the connection to the source file by using `Get-Content` and is why you should be seeing "InputStream" in your output. `Select-String` can take file objects from the pipeline directly so there is no need to convert them to string array first.

```
$path = "C:\temp"
$pattern = "dummy"
$outputPath = "c:\temp\kent.csv"
Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -Filter *.txt | Select-String -Pattern $pattern -SimpleMatch | 
    Select-Object Path,Line | Export-Csv $path -NoTypeInformation
```

I also used `-SimpleMatch` since regex is supported and your sample does not use it.

Comment: LIkely will add an update about grouping once I understand why and the desired output. Its easy to do but I don't want to guess.

Comment: Thanks Matt.  IF I remove the Select-obect path,linenumber portion, I get what I need.  If I leave the section above intact, I get the file name and the line number only... not content.

Comment: @NobleMan What _exactly_ do you need? I have several comments about how I am not sure what output you want. You can add to the select or just remove it if you do not need it

Comment: I have added an update in the main message on what I am looking for.

Comment: @NobleMan If you wanted the file and line in question then I just changed the select to `path,line`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse -filter *.log `
| %{$LogFile = $_.FullName; $_} `
| get-content `
| select-string -pattern "dummy" `
| group path `
| select name, @{N='LogFileName'; E={$LogFile}} `
| export-csv "c:\temp\kent.csv"
```

- You can ignore the backticks and new lines; those are just to make the code simpler to read here.
- `| %{$LogFile = $_.FullName; $_}` - Records the filename in a variable called `$LogFile`, then passes the content that it received on to the next element in the pipeline.
- `| select name, @{N='LogFileName'; E={$LogFile}}` - I've added a new column with Name `LogFileName` and value (expression) taken from the `$LogFile` variable populated earlier.

Comment: Thanks John, but for some reason I am only getting this:  
    Name InputStream LogFileName
InputStream C:\Logs\2\Logs\_SCNotify_CORPORATE@user_1.log
There are hundreds of entries with the content of "bethdc"  within the logs

Comment: Try removing the line `| group path `; I'd not spotted that on my first look through; at present that's adding no value (since there is no `path` at that stage, so it'll be grouping everything into a single line.

Comment: I have updated the original message to show what I need.

Comment: @JohnLBevan The matches object provided by Select-String does have a path property.